# Detect mouse right ckick on combobox

Tags: vb6

How to detect a mouse click (or mousedown) event on a simple dropdown combo (combobox with style=1)?

I am unable to see mouseclick or mousedown event handlers for combobox in my vb6 IDE.

My aim is to detect right click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the events aren't exposed, you may need to subclass the control and handle the WM_RBUTTONDOWN message.